# What happens when one query inserts and one alters the same table concurrently?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What will happen if one or more processes are trying to append data to the table and one or more processes are trying to alter the table at the same time?

Let's say we have a table called db.table(partitioned on band column):

```
band |name |age
---------------------------
 1        abc   18
 1        xyz   20
 2        aaa   18
 2        bbb   19
 3        ccc   22
 4        ddd   28
```

Alter command:

```
spark.sql("alter table db.table add columns (year_of_birth int, salary double, city string)")
```

Data append:

```
df = spark.sql("select 5 as band, 'fff' as name, 33 as age")

df.write.partitionBy('band').mode('append').saveAsTable('db.table')
```

Here df.write and spark.sql(alter command) are executing at the same time by multiple processes. What is the behaviour of spark in this scenario?

Comment: executing at the same time means how are you executing them at same time?

Comment: Using spark-submit.

Comment: if you that that using spark-submit then it wont happen at the same time. It would do all your work in parallel but when there is some shuffling or any task that needs to done separately it would separate it out to different stage or task at the time of execution

Comment: So, if one spark submit is trying to alter the table, and one spark submit is trying to insert data into the table. Will spark handle this, as you said that they won't occur at the same time?? I mean no errors/exception??

Comment: If you run two spark submit and both of them doing different things. The first operation would happen successfully and other might happen successfully or fail based on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Easy, nothing surprising would really happen since the data to be written to would be loaded before that data (as a table) would be appended to.

Moreover, append queries are safe since they get data added (not really modified on row basis).